# how to use ALL clause in mysql

Tags: mysql

i trying to fetch records from database as.

```
select * from emp_marks where sub_id all(2,4);
```

Comment: More info might be useful. What problem are you running into, exactly?

Comment: Shouldn't it be like sub_id in (2,4).

Comment: Not necessarily - 'all' is a distinct keyword in T-SQL and others: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178543.aspx That's why I asked him to elaborate on what his problem is.

Answer (score 2):

you can't use all with where clause, if you want to get all the records that have sub_id = 2 or 4 you can use:

```
select * from emp_marks where sub_id in (2,4)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the records where `sub_id` is either 2 or 4, you need

```
SELECT * FROM emp_marks WHERE sub_id IN (2,4);
```

if you want to records where `sub_id` is both 2 and 4, you don't have to perform query at all ;-)